# wikipedia API: parse a table as JSON?

Tags: json, api, mediawiki, wikipedia

Is it possible to parse [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#Partial_ISO_639_table) as array in array JSON?

The output I want is something like:

```
[
  ["Northwest Caucasian", "Abkhaz", "аҧсуа бызшәа, аҧсшәа", "ab", "abk", "abk", "abk", "abks"], 
  [Afro-Asiatic", "Afar", "Afaraf", "aa", "aar", "aar", "aar", "aars"],
  ...
]
```

The best I've got is like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=parse&page=List_of_ISO_639-1_codes&prop=sections), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=parse&page=List_of_ISO_639-1_codes&prop=text), or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), which isn't helpful at all.

I need not only the ISO639 table but some other wikipedia tables, so I need a general method of parsing wiki tables as json. Any ideas?

Comment: Nowadays you should use Wikidata. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access

Answer (score 8, accepted):

okay, I found the simplest way is to use Javascript in Chrome Developer Console

```
$('table.sortable tr').map(function() {
    return new Array($('td', this).map(function() {
        return $(this).text()
    }).slice(2, 5).get())
}).get()
```

It's a pity wikipedia doesn't provide an API like this.

Answer (score 2):

@est thanks, this helped me a lot.

You can also improve previous code to save the result as json string, just wrap it in  `JSON.stringify()` (Modern browsers only)

```
JSON.stringify($('table.sortable tr').map(function() {
    return new Array($('td', this).map(function() {
        return $(this).text()
    }).slice(2, 5).get())
}).get())
```